# Get queryset of related one to one fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models:

```
class BillingNumbering(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(default=now)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField(BillingNumbering, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                      null=True, blank=True)

class DamageClaim(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField(BillingNumbering, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                      null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to query only those `BillingNumbering` objects that is connected to either `Invoice` or `DamageClaim`.

So if I have

- `<BillingNumbering: 1>` - connected to invoice
- `<BillingNumbering: 2>` - connected to damage claim
- `<BillingNumbering: 3>` - connected to None where `instance.invoice` or `instance.damageclaim` will result to `ObjectDoesNotExist` Error.

Then I only want to return `<BillingNumbering: 1>` and `<BillingNumbering: 2>` with `BillingNumbering` **filter**

**UPDATED**

The answer of WoodyG below gave me an idea. I was able to solve it with below:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = BillingNumbering.objects.filter(Q(damageclaim__isnull=False) | Q(invoice__isnull=False))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `related_name` field to both `Invoice` and `DamageClaim`

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField(
        BillingNumbering,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="invoice_billing_number",
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

class DamageClaim(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField(
        BillingNumbering,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="damageclaim_billing_number",
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you should be able to query for the billing objects associated with Invoices and DamageClaims, respectivelly - like this:

```
invoice_billing = BillingNumbering.objects.values_list("invoice_billing_number")
damageclaim_billing = BillingNumbering.objects.values_list("damageclaim_billing_number")
```

Comment: Does not work perfectly with the queryset attribute of a django rest framework viewset

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```py
qs = BillingNumbering.objects.prefetch_related('invoice_set', 'demageclaim_set')
```

In case you are curious about where I'm getting `invoice_set` and `demageclaim_set`, these are the default name given by Django in case you don't provide any `related_name` in your `ForeignKey` or other relation fields. [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects:%7E:text=If%20a%20model%20has%20a%20ForeignKey%2C%20instances%20of%20the,manipulated%20as%20described%20in%20the%20%E2%80%9CRetrieving%20objects%E2%80%9D%20section%20above.) for more detail about `related_name`

Comment: Sorry but it did not work. It still included `<BillingNumbering: 3>`

Comment: I also am using `OneToOneField` and not `ForeignKey`